# What is a graph "weighted" with 3-dimensional vectors called?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, terminology

I'm trying to model a prism as a graph with edges "weighted" with 3D vectors so that they are relatively positioned and form a 3D solid. However, I don't know if I can call a "vector-weighted" graph a weighted graph. I want to use the correct nomenclature. I've researched a little and found something similar called Coxeter graphs but its complexity is out of my scope. How do I represent 3D solids with defined edges and vertices as graphs without going into these complex details?

Comment: You might think of a *geometric graph*. Weights are usually understood as scalar quantities, I wouldn't use this here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are describing a **spatial embedding** of a graph.